# Tor bundle doesn't open on Mac - help please!

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox, mac, help

I've downloaded the browser bundle, created a new folder in applications and moved it across from downloads to there. I've even moved it to the desktop and tried opening it. I've rebooted my Mac 3 times now too, after closing all programmes down. It still says Firefox is already open, and the application keeps attempting to open 2 Tor browsers, just before it gives me the "can't open because Firefox is already open" message. I don't have Firefox on my machine.

Any advice? I'm thinking I might bin it and try again? I somehow doubt that'll fix the problem though. There's obviously an issue with it running. I've looked through the answers to the same question, nothing is working and some of the advice is for Windows machines. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you could try moving it to a different folder other than applications. that's always worked for me, and i don't even have root privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes firefox does not close properly.
Press..... CTRL - ALT - DELETE. Choose Task Manager and close firefox.

This happens to me even without using TOR. I think it's an error with firefox directly.
I have had to do this with firefox for years. Not every time but it is quite often.

After you close firefox from tast manager you won't have this problem

Comment: I'm using a Mac, not a PC and I don't have Firefox. 

Thanks all the same :(

Answer (score 0):

I have a mac, and only see that error when I have Firefox running already.

To see if you have it running(The long way, I have a pc keyboard so I don't know the mac keystrokes. I'm guessing it's Apple-Tab if not continue on), go under Utilities and launch Activity Monitor.  Make sure the cpu button/tab is selected then under process names look for Firefox.  Quit the Firefox application.

I also configured Vidalia to start the tor browser. So under preferences for Vidalia, in the general tab, select Start a proxy application when Tor starts.  Enter /Applications/TorBrowser.app in the text box.  Then hit okay.

Now when you start vidalia, it will start TorBrowser automatically.

Sorry re-read your post.  When I installed I basically downloaded the dmg file TorBrowser-4.0-osx32_en-US.dmg.  Ran that which will mount the tor installer.  It comes up with the typical mac installer that has you drag the app into the applications folder.  Then go under applications and start Vidalia.